# How can I WebDriverWait and getText() if I have a text that is randomic made

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this HTML and I just want to get the "DE-3500-0086-E-001" part. This text value always will be different.

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
  <label>Resultado</label>
  <h4>
     <a id="body_lblResultadoNumero"href="javascript:
     __doPostBack('ctl00$body$lblResultadoNumero','')">DE-3500-0086-E-001</a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Before that i have to wait for this value appear because it comes to me after a button click. So i have to wait for something that I don't know the content (it's random). Can I wait for any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below solution::

**Using XPATH:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='col-lg-2']/h4/a")))
    print myElem.text
except TimeoutException:
    print "Loading took too much time!"
```

**Using ID:**

```
myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "body_lblResultadoNumero")))
    print myElem.text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `explicit wait` to make sure the link is displayed.

Imports needed.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

And below should be your code.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id ='body_lblResultadoNumero']"))).text
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the text is available, use `xpath` with this logic combination: `and text() != ''`.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='body_lblResultadoNumero' and text() !='']")))
print(element.text)
```